# error with ggplot in R3.1.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a simple bar graph in R, using `ggplot` in R3.1.1 on Windows 8. Here's a code segment:

```
ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=emotion))
+ geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=emotion))
+ scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
+ labs(x="emotion categories", y="number of comments")
+ opts(title = "classification by emotion", plot.title = theme_text(size=12))
```

with `sent_df` the dataframe, but getting an error:

> Error: Use 'theme' instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opts is not used anymore. Instead you have to use `theme` try this

```
    ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=emotion)) + geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=emotion)) + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + labs(x="emotion categories", y="number of comments",
title = "classification by emotion") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12))
```

For further details just look at ggplot2 documentation.

Comment: @Mudit Accept my answer if it works for you